# Settings screen appears all of a sudden

Tags: settings

Sometimes I'm not even touching my phone, sometimes I'm using it. It just goes to the settings screen without me telling it to do it. I'm on a Galaxy Note 3

Comment: What setting screen? Any special page? If so: Could it be related to any app you've recently installed/updated, e.g. providing a shortcut to exactly that page?

Comment: I've owned this phone for 4 months now and this issue has been present almost since the beginning.Any way to discover which app may be causing this? I mean the settings page of the phone with Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, etc

Comment: The main settings page, or some special sub-section (and always the same)? And could it have to do with the heavy modifications you did to your system? I'm pretty out of ideas what it could be (never heard of such behavior), so all I can do is "guess wildly"...

Comment: The first section of the settings, always. Isn't there a log of system activities from which I can try to see if there's an app triggering it?

Comment: You could try `adb logcat`, yes. If you don't have the SDK installed, and don't want to have its "full load": take a look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575). I only can recommend having at least the minimal variant available – be it for logcat or backup or ... ;)